# Prestashop 403 error with symfony connexion

Tags: api, symfony, prestashop

i ve a strange problem
i install prestashop library on symfony (iq2i/prestashop-webservice-bundle)
i can connect to two internet websites (one is http the other https)

but on the third i got the error:
{"message":"This call to PrestaShop Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:403"}

i ve this website install localy too on my computer with the same files as the remote one, and i can connect with symfony to my local website, but nope on the internet one...

i check rights, .htaccess ...

so i enable the debug and i got:
You don't have permission to access /api/products

an idea please ?

Comment: i checked provider log, i found:
[Fri Jun 15 16:28:52 2018] [error] [client 157.108.59.137] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache2/conf/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "65"] [id "960009"] [rev "2.1.1"] [msg "Request Missing a User Agent Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "www.thewebsite.fr"] [uri "/api/products"], somebody know what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have got the error:
[Fri Jun 15 16:28:52 2018] [error] [client 157.108.59.137] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/usr/local/apache2/conf/modsecurity/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "65"] [id "960009"] [rev "2.1.1"] [msg "Request Missing a User Agent Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"]

with OVH provider
on the root folder, you ve got a filename .ovhconfig

you have to add the following line:
modsecurity == WAF === http.firewall=security